# Python functions parameter

Tags: python

why append method works on original numbers list and it changed numbers list but I can't reassign  numbers list to [4,5,6]?

```
def change(numbers_list):
    numbers_list.append(4)
    numbers_list = [4,5,6]
numbers = [1,2,3]
change(numbers)
print(numbers)
```

when code runs this printed:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

why not [4,5,6]?

Comment: This PyCon talk explains the mechanisms at work here: Facts and Myths about Python Names and Values: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html

Comment: @NedBatchelder thank you! your presentation was wonderful

Answer (score -1):

The function of `append` is to add an item to an existing list. The reason for no effect is that you are doing many invalid things.  For one you are calling the function but never assigning the `return` to a `variable`.  Second your use of `append` is `void` because directly after you declare `numbers_list = [4, 5, 6]`. If you goal of the function is just to change `[1, 2, 3]` to `[4, 5, 6]` the setup would be this.

```
def change(numbers_list):
    numbers_list = [4,5,6]
    return numbers_list

numbers = [1,2,3]
numbers = change(numbers)
print(numbers)
# [4, 5, 6]
```

Although this would suffice

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
numbers = [4, 5, 6]
print(numbers)
# [4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: A function does not have to return anything explicitly, it will return `None` by default, and the return value of a function does not have to be assigned to a variable. Your answer did not explain the behaviour of OP's code: why 4 was appended to `numbers`, but `numbers` was not changed to `[4, 5, 6]` by the second line in the `change` function?

Comment: @ducminh good thing SO is an open community for as many as would like to post an answer if you have the ability to help OP better than I, you should invest that time into posting a response to guide him pointing out the flaws in my response :)

Comment: I believe it is better to explain to OP the behaviour of his/her code, since this problem might be confusing and trouble a lot of Python beginners. Also, OP explicitly asked about the strange behaviour of mutating a list when passed as an argument to a function. In this aspect, the talk of Ned Batchelder already did a great job explaining this behaviour.